# display line chart after clicking

Tags: javascript

I am using Visualization: Line Chart from google in this link 
https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart

and this is the code

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
      ['2004',  1000,      400],
      ['2005',  1170,      460],
      ['2006',  660,       1120],
      ['2007',  1030,      540]
    ]);

    var options = {
      title: 'Company Performance'
    };

    var chart = new    google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

my problem is when I use this code always display on the page 
and i want to display the line chart after clicking button

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you would like to do is something like this:

**DEMO:**      http://jsfiddle.net/K5aMG/3/

**JavaScript:**

```
    function showChart(){
      document.getElementById('mychart').style.display='block';
    }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="mychart" style="display:none;">     
   <div id="chart_div" style="width:900px; height: 500px;"></div>
</div>
<div onclick="showChart();">click here to show a chart </div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {
    packages: ["corechart"]
});

// bind a function to the onload event:
google.setOnLoadCallback(initialise);

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
        ['2004', 1000, 400],
        ['2005', 1170, 460],
        ['2006', 660, 1120],
        ['2007', 1030, 540]
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Company Performance'
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}

// the function bound to the onload event handler:
function initialise(){
    // getting a reference to the button element (that I added,
    // which isn't in your own code):
    var button = document.getElementById('showChart');
    // using a simple event-handler to bind a function to the onclick event:
    button.onclick = function () {
        // draw the chart:
        drawChart();
        // remove the button element:
        button.parentNode.removeChild(button);
    };
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/2qn4s/).

The above using the following HTML:

```
<button id="showChart">Show the chart</button>
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

The reason your own chart showed up as the page loaded, rather than on clicking a button element is that:

1. you called the `drawChart()` function in the onload event-handler (`google.setOnLoadCallback(drawchart)`), which caused it to be called immediately on page-load, and
2. you didn't have any button to click (in your posted HTML), or an event-handler to handle the click on that element (if it existed, but was, for some reason, not shown).